# In communist planet with one state, are all people shareholders?

Tags: communism

In communist planet with one state, are all people shareholders on all property?

Or rather there are two sets of properties --- one of the government faction and one of the non government faction?

What does theoretical literature about communism reveals to us?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi! Since this has never happened, we don't know how it would work. It is also unclear what exactly you mean by the word "shareholder" in this context.

Comment: Community and Giskard, I have edited to clarify, please kindly review and tell me if any further edits might be needed.

Comment: @unmarriedinquirer First, this question is more politics than economics. Second: there are no set rules for communism, there are many variants of this ideology, so I don't think you are likely to get a good answer even if you ask at [Politics.SE].

Comment: this question is moved to politics.se as it seems to discuss communism as political ideology not economic system (according to Marx's writings on working of communist economy in communism there isn't even supposed to be any state or property - however that would even work)

Comment: No, at least judging by experience of real Communist societies.  A small percentage of the people will be Party members, with privileges depending on their rank within the party.  The rest will effectively be serfs.

Comment: @jamesqf sounds a lot like non-Communist societies, just with a bigger gap. But is the question about communists or Communists?

Comment: Shareholding is a bourgeois capitalist concept. It has no meaning under socialism. If you are asking about control of capital assets, different strands of socialist strands of socialist thought have different answers.

Comment: @user253751: I don't understand what you mean by big vs little C communists.  And no, it does not seem like many non-[Cc]ommunist societies.

Comment: @jamesqf as far as I can tell, a small percentage of people in today's society are "Wealthrty" members with privileges depending on their rank within the "Wealthrty" and the rest are not so far away from being serfs. [cC]ommunists would call it the "owning class"